# Using weak self in dispatch_async function

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, weak-references, retain-cycle

I read a lot of posts about using `__weak self` inside `dispatch_async`, and now I am a litle bit confused.

if I have :

```
self.myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.biview.core_data", NULL);

dispatch_async(self.myQueue, ^(void){
    if (!self.var1) {
        self.var1 = ...;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        if ([self.var2 superview]) {
            [self.var2 removeFromSuperview];
        }

        [self.Label setText:text];
    });
});
```

do I need to use `__weak self`. Because I read that in some cases `dispatch_async`   not need a `__weak self`.

[See last comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806193/when-and-why-would-i-want-to-declare-a-local-variable-as-weak-using-arc)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Assuming, *self* is an object pointer to a `UIViewController`.

Things to consider:

- A `UIViewController` is a "UIKit" object. UIKit objects shall not be sent methods on non-main threads, that is - those methods must execute on the main thread only!
- A block that has been enqueued in a queue - whether this was synchronously or asynchronously - will eventually be *executed* -- no matter what!  Well, unless the program terminates before this can happen.
- Captured retainable *strong* pointers will be *retained* when the block will be copied (for example, when dispatched asynchronously), and again *released* when the block will be destroyed (after it finished).
- Captured retainable *weak* pointers will NOT be retained and not released.

In your scenario, where you capture *self* in the block which is dispatched on the *main queue*, you don't need to worry that bad things happen.

#### So, why? And what happens actually?

Since *self* will be *captured* in the block which is dispatched *asynchronously*, *self* will be implicitly *retained*, and *released* again when the block has been finished.

That means, the life-time of *self* will be *extended* up until after the block finishes. Notice that your *second* block is dispatched on the *main thread*, and it's guaranteed that *self* is still alive when that block gets executed.

This "extended life" above, might be a desired feature of your program.

If you *explicitly* don't want to extend the life-time of the `UIViewController` object, and instead want the block - when it finally executes - *check* whether this `UIViewController` object does still exist at all, you can use a __weak pointer of self. Note that the block gets eventually executed, no matter whether the `UIViewController` is still alive or has been deallocated in the mean time.

You might want the block doing "nothing" if the `UIViewController` has been deallocated *before* the block will get executed:

```
MyController* __weak weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    MyController* strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        ...
    }
    else {
       // self has been deallocated in the meantime.
    }
});
```

See also: [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

#### Remember: `UIKit` objects shall not be sent methods on non-main threads!

One other subtle error may occur due to the fact that `UIKit` objects shall execute methods only on the main thread.

This can be violated, if a block captures a `UIKit` object which is dispatched asynchronously, and executes on a *non-main* thread. It then may happen that the block holds the *last* strong reference to that `UIKit` object. Now, when the block gets eventually executed, the block will be destroyed and the `UIKit` object will be released. Since this is the last *strong* reference to the `UIKit` object, it will be deallocated. However, this happens on the thread where the block has been executed - and this is not the main thread! Now, bad things can (and will usually) happen, since the `dealloc` method is still a method sent to a `UIKit` object.

You can avoid this error, by dispatching a block capturing a strong pointer to that UIKit object, and send it a dummy method:

```
UIViewController* strongUIKitPointer = ... 
dispatch_async(non_main_queue, ^{
    ... // do something 
    dispatch(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [strongUIKitPointer self];  // note: self is a method, too - doing nothing
    });
});
```

In your scenario though, the *last strong* reference could be only in the block which executes on the main thread. So, you are safe from this subtle error. ;)

### Edit:

In your setup, you never have a retain cycle. A retain cycle occurs if a retainable object A strongly references another retainable object B, and object B strongly references A. Note that a "Block" is also a retainable object.

A contrived example with a cyclic reference:

```
typedef void(^my_completion_block_t)(NSArray* result);

@interface UsersViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, copy) my_completion_block_t completion;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray* users;
@end
```

Here, we have a property *completion* whose value type is a Block. That is, we get an ivar with name `_completion` whose type is a Block.

A client may set a completion handler which should be called when a certain operation has finished. Suppose, the operation fetches a list of Users from a remote server. The plan is to set the property *users* once the operation finished:

The careless approach would accidentally introduce a cyclic reference:

Somewhere in "UsersViewController.m"

```
self.completion = ^(NSArray* users){
    self.users = users;
}

[self fetchUsers];  // start asynchronous task
```

Here, *self* holds a strong reference to the ivar `_completion`, which is a block. And the block itself captures *self*, which causes to retain *self* when the block gets copied when it is dispatched. This is a classic reference cycle.

In order to avoid that cyclic reference, we have a few alternatives:

1. Using a `__weak` qualified pointer of *self*

   ```
   UsersViewController* __weak weakSelf = self;
   self.completion = ^(NSArray* users) {
       UsersViewController* strongSelf = weakSelf;
       if (strongSelf) {
           strongSelf.users = users;
       }
       else {
           // the view controller does not exist anymore
       }
   }   
   [usersViewController fetchUsers];
   ```
2. Using a `__block` qualified pointer of *self* and eventually setting it `nil` in the block when it finishes:

   ```
   UsersViewController* __block blockSelf = self;
   self.completion = ^(NSArray* users) {
       blockSelf.users = users;
       blockSelf = nil;
   }   
   [usersViewController fetchUsers];
   ```

See also: [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: wow, this was very informative answer, thanks. So if I understand correctly, if after `dispach_async` calling at least one function on the main thread, even if it is a dummy one it prevent to get retain cycle and I don't need `__weak` reference to self?

Comment: @MarkoZadravec In your setup, you never have a retain cycle. A retain cycle occurs if a retainable object A strongly references another retainable object B, and object B strongly references A. Note that a "Block" is also a retainable object. You will get a retain cycle if your ViewController has a strong block ivar, and that block will capture self: ViewController owns block, block owns ViewController. The latter is what you need to avoid.

Comment: Can you please give me a example of this. I think I understand, but I want to be shore.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec OK, I added an example which causes a retain cycle and solutions to prevent this.

Comment: Wow that was great. So If for example I use onelly ‘dispatch_async(self.coreDataQueue, ^(void){...‘ it can't get into retain cycle because this block doesn't have strong iVars to retain ‘self‘.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec Yes, at least no retain cycle involving _self_. Since self won't have a reference to the block, the block _can_ capture _self_ -- without introducing a retain cycle. Nonetheless, be careful: retain cycles can occur in more subtle and non-obvious scenarios.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper nice info about sending the dealloc message to an UIKit object in non-main thread. Didn't know about that. Cheers.

Comment: What in case of declaring the block in the scope of the method like `my_completion_block_t completion = ^(...){}`? In that case you shouldn't use a weak reference to self (same as `dispatch_` blocks), right?

Comment: @Priya There are certainly _several_ ways to accomplish this. This is however not related to this answer or the OP's question. I would suggest to ask this as a separate question on SO. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "Use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread or main dispatch queue, unless otherwise indicated. **This restriction particularly applies to classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way**." - [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit?language=objc), so it is not problematic if a view controller is called from a non-main thread and doesn't manipulate the UI

Comment: @ɯɐɹʞ You would not use a View Controller for functions not manipulating the UI. On the other hand, if you have an array of items as instance variable in a VC, and use that to render cells in a Table View, this array is already "manipulating" the UI - and it would be a data race to access the array from non-main threads - unless you synchronise the array and items explicitly.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, why would Apple put that disclaimer then?

Comment: @ɯɐɹʞ Well, it seems to be a fact, that there is "Thread confinement on the main thread" for UIKit functions, which means, any API in UIKit should be called only from the main thread. There are a few exceptions, though. These exceptions are mostly graphic related, which presumable use synchronisation primitives internally.
You should in fact not even just read seemingly simple properties from a non-main thread which just return some state as an integral value (Int), because actually this has been modified from some UI related function internally on the main thread. This is a data race.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, could we discuss this further in chat?

Answer (score 31):

### Swift update:

An example of this so-called strong-weak dance in swift:

### Swift 4.2:

```
func doSomeThingAsynchronously() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // Do task in default queue
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            // Do task in main queue
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.updateView()
        }
    }
}
```

### Swift 3 & 4:

```
func doSomeThingAsynchronously() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // Do task in default queue
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            // Do task in main queue
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            strongSelf.updateView()
        }
    }
}
```

### Swift 2:

```
func doSomeThingAsynchronously() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> () in
        // Do task in default queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [weak self] () -> () in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            // Do task in main queue
            strongSelf.updateView()
        })
    }
}
```

Popular open source project **`Alamofire`** uses this approach.

> Extend object lifetime using the **[weak self]** and **guard let** strongSelf = self else { return } idiom.

For more info check out [swift-style-guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide/blob/master/README.markdown)

Comment: Fun fact: you can avoid the `strongSelf`syntax in swift with ```guard let `self` = self else { return }```

Comment: The use of ``self`` is actually a compiler bug and may be removed in future releases of Swift. See the full explanation from Swift's Chris Lattner, here: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html