# Objective-C Blocks: Is it ok to modify self in an external method if called from a weak pointer to self?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

Can you modify self from an instance method called from a weak self pointer within a block?

```
-(void)someMethod:(AnotherClassName *)anObject {

    __weak MyClassName *weakSelf = self;

    [anObject requestSomethingWithCompletion:^{
        [weakSelf updateSomething];
    }];
}

-(void)updateSomething {
    self.something = @"update"; // Will this cause a memory leak?
}
```

So basically I am calling an instance method from the same class I am in, but I am doing it from a weak pointer and then changing `self`.

According to [Apple's Programming with Objective-C Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) this is how to call a method on `self` within a block but it isn't clear weather I can directly modify `self` in that method.

If you know the answer based on something you've read before please include the source.

Thanks!

Comment: Nitpicking but important distinction: you are not "modifying" `self`, nor do you "change" `self` - where `self` is a _pointer to an object_ (and not the _object_ itself). Instead, you are sending methods to the _object_ where _self_ points to and possibly modifying the object. This distinction is important to understand the subtleties when object pointers are involved in Blocks ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Wouldn't calling the setter of a property, or more specifically sending the message `[self setSomething:@"update"]` be modifying the object self points to?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. The class itself can implement its own setter and that might or might not modify the underlying instance variable and make a change to self.

Comment: A setter property will (likely) modify the object - however, _self_ **itself** - which is a pointer to that object remains the same. In fact, if a block captures a strong pointer to any object (not just self), it cannot "modify" that pointer, e.g.: `obj = anotherObject;` within the block would issue a compiler error something like "Cannot modify variable 'obj'"

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just thinking along the same lines.

Comment: OK, then you need to know what the `__block` modifier will do: if the block captures a variable with a `__block` modifier, the block actually captures a _reference_ to that variable. Within the block you can now modify that variable which actually exists *outside* the block. Sure you need to ensure that this "outside" variable is still existing when the block gets executed.

Comment: Ok, so I would want to use that for local variables that are not properties and for properties I would use a weak self to modify them

Comment: Korey, the whole topic is more complex and a thorough explanation won't fit into comments. I've written an answer recently which may help, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987067/using-weak-self-in-dispatch-async-function/21988407#21988407

Comment: That's very thorough, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify properties and call methods. There will be no memory leaks.

But your block is not thread safe now. If `requestSomethingWithCompletion` will run block asynchronously your class (`self`) could be deallocated during block execution and `weakSelf` will become nil. This could cause problems (depends on what does your block do). Good practice to avoid this is to write it following way

```
-(void)someMethod:(AnotherClassName *)anObject {

    __weak MyClassName *weakSelf = self;

    [anObject requestSomethingWithCompletion:^{
        MyClassName *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf updateSomething];
    }
}

-(void)updateSomething {
    self.something = @"update"; // No leaks here!
}
```

Comment: Actually, the way a weak pointer is implemented, guarantees in the OP's case that you don't need to worry about whether _self_ has been deallocated. In that case, _dereferencing_ (means _using_ it) the weak pointer returns a `nil` value - and it is safe to send messages to `nil`. However, your suggested Idiom is actually the preferred one, since it actually avoids such subtle issues that when having multiple _dereferences_ of the weak pointer return first an object then subsequently `nil` - since it has been deleted in the meantime. Getting a strong pointer again safely retains that object.

Comment: Your code is exactly the same as the OP's code. See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics "Reading occurs when performing a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an object lvalue.

    For __weak objects, the current pointee is retained and then released at the end of the current full-expression. This must execute atomically with respect to assignments and to the final release of the pointee."