# Closures vs Delegate pattern

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, closures

I'm working with network request classes and I'm concerned about **crashes**. For instance, working with closures is really easy as you pass a callback method to a function:

```
// some network client
func executeHttpRequest(#callback: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    // http request

    callback(true)
}

// View Controller
func reload() {
    networkClient.executeHttpRequest() { (success) -> Void in
        self.myLabel.text = "it succeeded" // NOTE THIS CALL
    }
}
```

However, since the process that should execute the callback is async, when callbacks interact with container class element (in this case an `UIKit` class) it may be vulnerable to crashes in situations like

1. The user navigated to another View Controller while the async task was still executing
2. The user pressed the home button while the async task was still executing
3. Etc...

So, when the callback finally gets fired, `self.myLabel.text` might result in a crash, as the View Controller to whom `self` was refering could already be deallocated.

**Up to this point. Am I right or do swift implement something internally so that this never happens?**

If I am right, then here's when the delegate pattern comes in handy, as delegate variables are `weak references`, which means, they are not kept in memory if deallocated.

```
// some network client

// NOTE this variable is an OPTIONAL and it's also a WEAK REFERENCE
weak var delegate: NetworkClientDelegate?

func executeHttpRequest() {
    // http request

    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate.callback(success: true)
    }
}
```

Note how `self.delegate`, since it is a `weak reference`, it will point to `nil` if the View Controller (who implements the `NetworkClientDelegate` protocol) gets deallocated, and the callback is not called in that case.

My question would be: do closures have anything special that makes them a good choice in scenarios similar to this one, rather than going back to delegate pattern? It would be good if examples of closures (that won't end up in crashes due to nil pointer) are provided. Thanks.

Comment: Well your first one won't crash, since referencing self in the block prevents it from being deallocated while the block is still alive.

Comment: Small Swift tip: Use `delegate?.callback(success: true)` instead of `if let delegate = self.delegate { delegate.callback(success: true) }`. Also you wouldn't need the `self` to access a property ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> So, when the callback finally gets fired, self.myLabel.text might result in a crash, as the View Controller to whom self was referring could already be deallocated.

If `self` has been imported into the closure as a strong reference, it is guaranteed that `self` will *not* be deallocated up until the closure has been finished executing. That is, the view controller is still alive when the closure gets called - even if it's view is not visible at this time. Statement `self.myLabel.text = "it succeeded"` will be executed, but even the label will not be visible, it will not crash.

There is, though, a subtle issue which can lead to a crash under certain circumstances:

Suppose, the closure has the last and only strong reference to the view controller. The closure finishes, and subsequently gets deallocated, which also releases the last strong reference to the view controller. This inevitable will call the `dealloc` method of the view controller. The `dealloc` method will execute on the same thread where the closure will be executed. Now, that the view controller is a `UIKit` object, it MUST be guaranteed that all methods send to this object will be executed on the *main thread*. So, IFF `dealloc` will be actually executed on some other thread, your code may crash.

A suitable approach would require to "cancel" an asynchronous task whose result is no longer needed by the view controller when it is "closed". This, of course, requires that your "task" can be cancelled.

To alleviate some issues with your former approach, you might capture a *weak* reference of your view controller instead of a *strong* reference when defining the closure. This would not prevent the asynchronous task to run up to its completion, but in the completion handler you can check whether the view controller is still alive, and just bail out if it does not exists anymore.

And, if you need to "keep" an UIKit object in some closure which may execute on some arbitrary thread, take care that this might be the *last* strong reference, and ensure this last strong reference gets released on the *main* thread.

See also: [Using weak self in dispatch_async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987067/using-weak-self-in-dispatch-async-function/21988407#21988407)

*Edit:*

> My question would be: do closures have anything special that makes them a good choice in scenarios similar to this one, rather than going back to delegate pattern?

I would say, closures are the "better" approach in many use-cases:

Delegates are more prone to issues like circular references than closures (since they are "owned" by an object, and this object might be captured as a variable in the delegate).

The classic use-case for closure as completion handlers also improves the "locality" of your code making it more comprehensible: you state *what* shall happen when a task finished *right after* the statement invoking the task - no matter how long that may take.

The huge advantage with closures versus regular "functions" is that a closure captures the whole "context" at the time when it is defined. That is, it can refer to variables and "import" them into the closure at the time when it is defined - and use it when it executes, no matter *when* this happens, and when the original "stack" at definition-time is gone already.

Comment: I chose your answer since it has a complete explanation of how it works internally.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use closures since they are more convenient and flexible than delegation in this scenario.

Regarding the user navigating to other view controllers and the async operation still executing in the background you could keep a reference to those operations and whenever the user navigates away from the view controller you could cancel them.

Alternatively, you could verify if the view controller's view is visible before updating the UI:

```
viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window
```

Regarding the app entering background/foreground, you could pause/resume the operations by overridng the `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` or registering for the appropriate notifications: `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` / `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`

I highly recommend you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) since it's API offers all the things I mentioned above, and much more.