# Referencing UIView subclass .center with Swift 3 #keyPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, key-value-observing

In a view controller in my app, I'm reacting to changes to a view's positioning by key-value observing its `center` property, like this:

```
class CoordinatingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardContainerView: CardView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "cardContainerView.center", options: [.new], context: nil)
    }
}
```

This works just fine for now, but since that key path is a string, it can't be checked by the compiler. To mitigate this, I'd like to use Swift 3's `#keyPath()` syntax, which takes a compiler-checked key path and returns the proper corresponding string. However, when I change that line to use it like this:

```
addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(cardContainerView.center), options: [.new], context: nil)
```

The compiler gives me 2 errors:

> 1. Type 'CardView!' has no member 'center'
> 2. Cannot refer to type member 'center' within instance of type 'CardView!'

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors, as [`center`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622627-center) is a documented property of `UIView`, which `CardView` inherits from directly, which I can both read and write to outside the `#keyPath()` statement there. Furthermore, everything appears to work ok when I pass the key path directly as a string, as in my first example, which makes this even more confusing. How can I have the compiler check that key path for me?

Comment: Try removing the `weak` modifier. I don't know why but it works for me...

Comment: Interesting! That seems to work for me, too. That being said, I'm timid to remove it, because it was added by Interface Builder. Would removing it cause a retain cycle or have any other side effects? I'm not aware of it being involved in any retain cycles in *my* code, even with the `weak` modifier gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Swift is not happy about the `weak` modifier. Remove it and the code will compile. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc), we can see that outlets are recommended to be strong, unless you actually have a retain cycle. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41661291/5133585) for how to find retain cycles.

In Swift 4, you will be able to do this, using the new `\` key path syntax:

```
// no problems with "weak"!
let observation = observe(\.cardContainerView.center) { (object, change) in
    ...
}
```