# Why deinit is not called?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code.
I don't understand why deinit is not called.

```
class SplashVC: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        print("SplashVC created")
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
            self?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(SignupViewController(), animated: true)
        }
    }
    deinit {
        print("SplashVC free")
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry If I don't understand well. I'm using `self?.navigationController?.popViewController`

Comment: Use [the method described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660486/knowing-where-retain-cycles-are-and-removing-them/41661291#41661291) to find out what is keeping a reference to your VC object.

Comment: Uh, creating an animation from the initializer is ugly. Also note that you can replace the controllers in the navigation stack directly, you don't need to pop.

Answer (score 4):

I read the documentations and now I know that pop root view controller was my problem.

> This method removes the top view controller from the stack and makes
>   the new top of the stack the active view controller. If the view
>   controller at the top of the stack is the root view controller, this
>   method does nothing. In other words, you cannot pop the last item on
>   the stack

Answer (score 3):

Probably your `SplashVC` is the root view controller in your navigation controller. If this is indeed the case, use this code instead:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
        self?.navigationController?.setViewControllers([SignupViewController()], animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `deinit` method is not called because memory allocated for `SplashVC` is not freed.

You're simply pushing another `UIViewController` on the `UINavigationController`. The `UINavigationController` still stores all view controllers you have pushed to it, hence the memory allocated for each view controller is still allocated

You used the `weak self` as a measure to ensure there is no memory leak or retain cycle, but the `deninit` method in this case will only be called when `SplashVC` is popped from its `UINavigationController`. Until you pop the view controller, the memory allocated will still remain allocated and unavailable for other use.