# Custom Delegate function not called befor UIAlertController SubClass Dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, cocoapods

I Created a subclass of UIAlertController which do some stuff but befor dimissing it i call Delegate (is a custom protocol for delegation pattern to use this in UIViewController) right befor dimiss statement

- Inserted this Code in my Custom Alert Class.
- I have a strong reference from it in UIViewController and set delegate to self.
- Conforming protocol and set a break point never reached during runtime.

```
// this code in my custom subClass of UIAlertController 

   func addRequestAction() {
        addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.checkConnection { isConnected in
                print("xxxxxxxxx", isConnected)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if isConnected {
                        self?.delegate?.didConnect() // here i call delegate function but never executed
                        self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        let alert = NetworkCheckerAlert(self?.delegate)
                        self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
                        guard let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController else { return }
                        viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
    }
```

Comment: What it tells when attempting to debug? Adding a breakpoint in the `handler` closure leads to...?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the `[weak self]`? Does `xxxxxxxxx` get printed? Does `checkConnection` get called?

Comment: Could you please check `self` and `delegate` at the `self?.delegate?.didConnect()` line? I think you are having this issue since the `delegate` is `nil` here. If you like to add your delegate configuration code samples into your question I want to solve the issue with you.

Comment: in the debugger self is nil when I put checkpoint at print("xxxxx)@AhmadF

Comment: but could any one explain to me why self is nil while alert not dismissed yet ?? @Sweeper

Comment: We don't actually know that `self` is nil. It could be that `checkConnection` is not called at all. I asked those questions because they are the things that I would check in such a situation. Please answer them.

Comment: no checkConnection is called and isConnected is just a Bool value to indicate whether I am connected to internet or not if i turn wifi on or off  get into if and else blocks so code is correct and the problem solved when i removed [weak self] but i don't know why ? and thanks in advence  @Sweeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `[weak self]` should solve the problem:

```
addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { /*[weak self]*/ _ in
```

Normally in a view controller, using `[weak self]` is fine because the `self` refers to the VC, but here `self` refers to the `UIAlertController`.

I'm assuming you are not retaining the reference to your custom alert controller when you are presenting it (i.e. you just declare it as a local variable, present it, and throw it away).

Now let’s consider what happens when the `DispatchQueue` closure is run. At this point, the alert has already been dismissed, so “the screen” is not retaining a reference to it. Since nothing is retaining a strong reference to the alert controller (only a weak reference from the closure exists), The instance of `UIAlertController` subclass is deallocated.

This is just a guess though. You can do more investigation by seeing which objects are in memory, and who are holding a reference to whom using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41661291/5133585) (written by me).