# Understanding retain cycles in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, rx-swift

If I have the following code

```
func handle(showEmptyView: Driver<Bool>) {
    showEmptyView
        .drive(onNext: setEmptyViewShown)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

func setEmptyViewShown(_ show: Bool) {
    tableView.isHidden = !show
    emptyView.isHidden = show
}
```

Is this a retain cycle when I call `setEmptyViewShown` because I don't use `weak` or `unowned` self?

Comment: Why don't you check with the Profiler, which will tell you with 100% certainty if you have a retain cycle?

Comment: Do you know you can check whether retain cycles _actually exist_ using Xcode? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660486/knowing-where-retain-cycles-are-and-removing-them/41661291#41661291).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a retain cycle because `setEmptyViewShown(_:)` is a method which takes `self` as an implicit first argument.

Better would be something like:

```
disposeBag.insert(
    showEmptyView.bind(to: emptyView.rx.isHidden),
    showEmptyView.map { !$0 }.bind(to: tableView.rx.isHidden)
)
```

Comment: Oh nice, I hadn't come across `insert` before

Comment: could I suggest drive instead of bind